# Append to already fetched collection - eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 methods like:

```
public function personSearch(Request $request)
    {
        $day = $request['day'];
        $people = Person::where('day', $day)->get();
        Session::put('people', $people);
        return $people;
    }
```

And another one to output to PDF:

```
public function generatePdf(Request $request)
{
    $people     = Session::get('people');
    if ($request['personalId'] == "true") {
        $people = $people->where('uid', 'like', 9999)->get();
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility to append additional condition on already created collection of data?

Comment: try `$people = collect(Session::get('people'));` and keep the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to merge the two collections like

```
$original = new Collection(['foo']);
$latest = new Collection(['bar']);
$merged = $original->merge($latest);
```

or you could change the two collections into arrays `->toArray()` and user array_merge method

I hope I understood your question correctly